# Maven plugin - edit files in target (war)

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I am developing some little maven plugin and I need to edit some css and js files from target (not from src!). And I can't understand on what phase I can do it.

To get access to src I use the `phases:generate-resources` and the following code:

```
MavenProject project = (MavenProject) getPluginContext().get("project");
String projectDir=project.getBasedir().toString();
```

How can I get target when all js,css files are copied there but war file is not generated in order to edit some files from target and get final war with some modifications of js and css files?

**EDIT**
What for I need it. I have js files in my project: a.js, b.js. I want to obfuscate them via maven. I mean, obfuscate when I build project. And of course all files in final war must be obfuscated but the same files in src must be left unobfuscated.
Besides, I need to combine some obfuscated files into one file.

Comment: What is the purpose of that and why do you like to do this?

Comment: @khmarbaise I need do some operations with js (obfuscate them and form bundles of some of them)

Comment: @khmarbaise Is my approach to solve such problem wrong?

Comment: Why don't you obfuscate before generating the war ?

Comment: Can you show you full source code and the appropriate pom file from your plugin otherwise it's hard to guess what's wrong..

Comment: @fxm I don't understand your question. I do want to obfuscate before generating the war. I want to do it via maven. And I want to remove from final war unobfuscated files but of course to keep them in src.

Comment: @khmarbaise I posted the answer.

Comment: @fxm I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The problem is that we must add some logic between "prepare-package" and "package" phases. As we user maven-war-plugin we can do it using `exploded` goal. From official docs:

> Create an exploded webapp in a specified directory.

And here it's necessary to remember one important thing that maven after version 2.0.1 copies resources twice so if we want to use maven 2.5 we must use `<useCache>true</useCache>`. So final solution:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>prepare-war</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>exploded</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <useCache>true</useCache>    
 </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>my plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>....</version>
    <executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>...</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```