# Maven-war-plugin - remove files

Tags: java, javascript, maven

I am developing maven plagin that obfuscates js files. It does the following -:

1. takes *.js files from target,
2. obfuscates them using google closure,
3. creates *.min.js files in target,
4. if it's necessary removes sources (unobfuscated files) from target.

In order to get point between package phase and prepare-package phase I use the following solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27566620/2022068

Everything is ok. Plugin is ready. However I have the following problem - if I remove source file, maven-war-plugin copies it again. Maybe it has some mechanism of checking - I don't know. The only thing that I can do now is to delete and create empty file. Than the source file exists but it's empty.

My qeustion - can I somehow remove files from target finally, forever...?

Comment: Why not doing it before the files are being copied to target folder?  And why not using existing plugins like https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise It's the second time you ask me the same questions. I need this functionality for what I want to do. I need my plugin because it must do what I want to do. That's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to teach this to the maven-war-plugin. I have no example that does the same thing but there are packageExcludes (see: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html) which seems not exactly what you need but also warSourceExcludes: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceExcludes

The war plugin has its own mechanism of copying files (aside from the resources plugin). That may be the issue here. There are some examples on filtering as well: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html

Maybe treating the files you don't want to see as excludes will work (if warSourceExcludes is something different than what you plan to do).

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem is that I add/remove files dynamically (from my maven plugin) but not from pom configuration.

Comment: can't you add / remove files according to a certain pattern? like using folder names / defaults for the original files and the obfuscated ones? The filters support some of the ANT expressions, without knowing or being able to rely on a convention you're doomed to unpack the war and delete the files you know should not be there. That seems not the best solution :/

Comment: Yes, I also think about this solution: patterns + include/exclude. However they create additional problems when my plugin is very powerful and easy in using. However, if I can solve this problem I will use patterns. (Unpacking is totally bad :))

Comment: You know what I'm afraid of - if I exclude all .js files and will copy them by myself maven-war-pluing will remove them. I mean the files I copied myself.

Comment: But it looks the life-cycle is quite ok? Maybe you need to do your work first, then let the war plugin copy stuff around but configure it to exclude what you have obfuscated? Another option would be to fork the war plugin and include yours into that one if everything else fails?

Comment: Thank you for good ideas. I did this way - in war plugin I exclude all js. I copy necessary js files by myself (via my plugin). It's ok as my plugin has its own exclude directives. Thank you.